# Hyperledger fabric Kubernetes chaincode instantiation fails

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I've deployed Hyperledger fabric 1.2.0 using Kubernetes on AWS consisting of 1 orderer, 2 org each containing 2 peers 1 cli and 1 ca. I am able to create a channel and join them as well as install chaincode but when I try to instantiate the chaincode it gives following error:

> peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer0.orgorderer1:7050 -C mychannel
>   -n test -v 2.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}'
>
> Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg failed to execute transaction
>   026ff5f4d1e5c3a0cb7a60f4768e327041396a50134375ba6ba8c8066ecb21f9:
>   error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate
>   platform-specific docker build: could not decode url: ChaincodeSpec's
>   path/URL invalid.

Comment: Hi,
Did you join the channel for both organizations? And did you install the chaincode for both organizations as well?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, me I had a similar situation and was a corrupted library in vendor, you can try go build on dev env probably you are getting the same compile error. Let me know what it says

Comment: While instantiating a new chaincode it creates a container and the kubernetes network don't have the knowledge of this chaincode container. Read this for more information https://medium.com/kokster/simpler-setup-for-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-using-docker-in-docker-8346f70fbe80